# Use image type in form submit button in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to use the form submit button with image type. How is this possible in Zend Framework 2?

I have the code for normal submit button:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'send',
    'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'submit',
        'value' => 'Send',
    ),
));
```

I tried changing the type to 'Zend\Form\Element\Image' or setting type to 'image', but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In form class

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'image',
            'src'   => './images/signin.png',
            'height'=> '28',
            'width' => '98',
            'border'=> '0',
            'alt'   => 'SIGN IN'
        ),
    ));
```

In .phtml

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend\Form\Element\Image required 'src' attribute, usage like below:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$form->add(array(
    'name' => 'send',
    'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Image',
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => 'Send',
        'src' => 'abc.jpg',
    ),
));

$helper = new Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormImage();
echo $helper($form->get('send'));
//output <input type="image" name="send" src="abc.jpg">
```